# ng-class to compare string

Tags: angular, ng-class

I need to set green dot class if the person is available and set red dot if the person is busy. "available" or "busy" is a string which will be the response from API. I tried to set the class using ng-class but it's not working for me

```
<div ng-class="{'led-green': {{person_list.person_available}} == 'available'}, {'led-red': {{person_lists.person_available}} == 'busy'}"></div>
```

Comment: Remove the double curly braces. You're **already** inside an Angular expression.

Comment: And it's [ngClass], not ng-class if you're using Angular. AnguarJS and Angular are two different frameworks.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to change it to:

```
<div [ngClass]="{
                 'led-green': person_list.person_available === 'available',
                 'led-red': person_lists.person_available === 'busy'
                }">
</div>
```

Differences are:

1. Use data binding by `[ngClass]`
2. Remove the extra `{{}}`
3. Use `===` instead of the `==`

Answer (score -1):

it should look like this:

```
<div ng-class="{person_list.person_available === 'available' ? 'led-green' : 'led-red' }"></div>
```